# Toggle Multiple divs for show hide

Tags: javascript, jquery, show-hide, function-parameter

ok, So I have multiple divs(7) which I want to toggle for show hide. If one div is open rest should hide and when I open a new div the others should hide. I have been able to accomplish this with the below piece of jquery

```
function showDivs() {
    $(".head").click(function() {
        $(".Content").hide();
        $(this).next().fadeIn("slow");

    })
}
```

where `.head` is the header for each div and `.Content` is the class for divs. I have got it working perfectly, by calling `showDivs()` from `.head()` Now the question is that on the left hand side of my page, I have `ul li` set. I have 7 `li` items, that correspond to 7 divs. I mean on click of first `li` the corresponding `div` should open up and the others should hide, and  on click of 2nd `li` the 2nd `div` should open up and the others hide.

Does anybody have an idea how to make these divs show hide on the action of `li` items on left. I know I have to pass parameters for `showDivs()`, but don't know how?

help is appreciated

Comment: Would you please change your username to something useful? As it is, I'm fairly certain no one can specifically target you in a comment via `@` notation... (You'll be notified of *this* comment because I'm commenting on your question.)

Comment: can you quote your HTML? Both the `div`s and the list.

Comment: I posted it here http://jsfiddle.net/DTcGD/24/

Comment: @ Tester: Live links are a great *adjunct* to a question, but always post the relevant code *in the question* as well. Two reasons. 1. People shouldn't have to follow a link to help you. 2. StackOverflow is meant to be a resource not just for you now, but for others having a similar issue in the future. External links can get moved, modified, deleted, etc. By making sure the relevant code is in the question, we ensure that the question (and its answers) remain useful for a reasonable period of time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe this is where `.index()` comes into play:

```
$(function() {
    $('ul li').each(function() {
        $(this).click(function(e) {
            var i = $(this).index();
            $('div').hide();
            $('div:eq('+i+')').show();
        });
    });
});
```

That's a pretty basic markup but I'm sure you can work out how to get it working with your code. Hope I helped!

http://jsfiddle.net/Z3Hj7/

**EDIT**: After having seen your fiddle I think i worked out exactly what you want:

```
$(function() {
    $('ul li').each(function() {
        $(this).click(function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            var i = $(this).index();
            $('.content').hide();
            $('.head:eq('+i+')').next().show();
        }); 
    });
});
```

Take a look at the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/DTcGD/25/

Comment: I think you've missed that his header and content divs are peers of one another (as witnessed by the `next()` call in `showDivs`), so the targeting there will be a bit off.

Comment: @Crowder It's quite hard to get a sense of his HTML markup since he hasn't posted it so all I could do really was give him a guide. Something tells me he will know what to do with that, if not he'll have to post his markup if possible.

Comment: Yes, as I commented on the question, we need to see the HTML. But it's absolutely clear from the code that the "head" and "Content" divs are peers (as was also clear from my comment above).

Comment: Thanks a Ton, Very helpful. Just a stupid question, why are you passing function  a parameter "e", what does this do.

Comment: @Tester Used 'e' as the event (click event). Then prevented the default click action (href target) that way if you have any href's on it, it won't go anywhere ;)

Answer (score 0):

How about asigning an id to each list item and a corosponding id to each item container. So your list items get an id of "item01".."item07" and your content containers gets id of "item01c".."item07c". Then you can do somehing like this:

```
$("li").click(function() {
    showDivs($(this).attr("id"));
})

function showDivs(callerId) {
  $(".content").hide();
  $(".content", "#" + callerId + "c").fadeIn();  
}
```

Working example can be seen here: http://jsfiddle.net/ECbkd/5/[1](http://jsfiddle.net/ECbkd/)

Comment: but this works only for ul li, what about individual div headers.

Comment: take a look at my alternative answer

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your HTML structure correctly, it looks about like this:

```
<!-- The list... -->
<ul>
  <li>One</li>
  <li>Two</li>
  <li>Three</li>
  <li>Four</li>
</ul>

<!-- The divs -- note I've assumed there's a container... -->
<div id="container">
  <div class="head">Header One</div>
  <div class="Content">Content One</div>
  <div class="head">Header Two</div>
  <div class="Content">Content Two</div>
  <div class="head">Header Three</div>
  <div class="Content">Content Three</div>
  <div class="head">Header Four</div>
  <div class="Content">Content Four</div>
</div>
```

...only with seven items rather than four.

If so, this would do it ([live copy](http://jsbin.com/ihukuk)):

```
jQuery(function($) {

  $(".Content").hide();

  $("li").click(function() {
    showDivs($("#container div.head:eq(" + $(this).index() + ")"));
  });
  $(".head").click(function() {
    showDivs($(this));
  });

  function showDivs(head) {
    $(".Content").hide();
    head.next().fadeIn("slow");
  }

});
```

There, I'm relating the list to the headers implicitly, by where they are in their container. So the first `li` relates to the first `div` with class="head", the second to the second, etc. I'm doing that by using [`index`](http://api.jquery.com/index/) to know which `li` was clicked, and then looking up the related `div.head` using [`:eq`](http://api.jquery.com/eq-selector/).

Doing it structurally rather than with `id` values makes it much easier to maintain. Alternately, though, you could do it by giving each `li` a `data-div` attribute with the value of the `id` of the related div:

```
<ul>
  <li data-div="h1">One</li>
  <li data-div="h2">Two</li>
  <li data-div="h3">Three</li>
  <li data-div="h4">Four</li>
</ul>
<div id="container">
  <div id="h1" class="head">Header One</div>
  <div class="Content">Content One</div>
  <div id="h2" class="head">Header Two</div>
  <div class="Content">Content Two</div>
  <div id="h3" class="head">Header Three</div>
  <div class="Content">Content Three</div>
  <div id="h4" class="head">Header Four</div>
  <div class="Content">Content Four</div>
</div>
```

Then ([live copy](http://jsbin.com/ihukuk/2)):

```
jQuery(function($) {

  $(".Content").hide();

  $("li").click(function() {
    showDivs($("#" + $(this).attr("data-div")));
  });
  $(".head").click(function() {
    showDivs($(this));
  });

  function showDivs(head) {
    $(".Content").hide();
    head.next().fadeIn("slow");
  }

});
```

[`data-*` attributes](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/elements.html#embedding-custom-non-visible-data-with-the-data-attributes) are valid as of HTML5, but all browsers support them right now. (The `data-*` thing is an attempt to codify and reign in people's use of invalid attributes, by giving them a valid way to do it without conflicting with future additions to the spec.)

Comment: *cries* But I wrote one too! http://jsfiddle.net/jamwaffles/WWWDn/ Darn those quick fingers of yours T.J!

Comment: Although I think mine is missing some functionality *wipes snot down sleeve*.

Comment: I've asked the same question on quite a few of my answers today. The Downvote Ninjas of Silence have struck once more.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use .index() as suggested by someone earlier, then I belive this would be the simplest approach (check it out here http://jsfiddle.net/ECbkd/7/):

```
$("li").click(function() {
    $(".content").hide();
    $('.item').eq($(this).index()).children('.content').fadeIn();
})
```

You could add this to be able to show content when clickin on header also:

```
$("h2", ".container").click(function() {
    $(".content").hide();
    $(this).parent().children('.content').fadeIn();
})
```

*** EDIT START ***
To let content toggle on click at header use this:

```
$("h2", ".container").click(function() {
    $(".content").not($(this).parent().children('.content')).hide();
    $(this).parent().children('.content').toggle();
})
```

Updated code here 
http://jsfiddle.net/ECbkd/8/
*** EDIT END ***

This is based on html like this:

```
<ul>
    <li>Item 01</li>
    <li>Item 02</li>
    <li>Item 03</li>
    <li>Item 04</li>
    <li>Item 05</li>
    <li>Item 06</li>
    <li>Item 07</li>
</ul>
<div class='container'>
    <div class='item'>
        <h2>Header 1</h2>
        <div class='content'>Content 1</div>        
    </div>        
    <div class='item'>
        <h2>Header 2</h2>
        <div class='content'>Content 2</div>       
    </div>
    <div class='item'>
        <h2>Header 3</h2>
        <div class='content'>Content 3</div>       
    </div>
    <div class='item'>
        <h2>Header 4</h2>
        <div class='content'>Content 4</div>       
    </div>
    <div class='item'>
        <h2>Header 5</h2>
        <div class='content'>Content 5</div>       
    </div>
    <div class='item'>
        <h2>Header 6</h2>
        <div class='content'>Content 6</div>       
    </div>
    <div class='item'>
        <h2>Header 7</h2>
        <div class='content'>Content 7</div>       
    </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Again the div headers don't do hide collapse

Comment: And heres a working example based on your html code posted above:
http://jsfiddle.net/DTcGD/26/

Answer (score 0):

you can show and hide multiple divs by using this simple method

```
function w3_open() { 
     document.getElementById("id01").style.display = 
    "block"; document.getElementById("id02").style.display = "block"
     }
```

make sure that you are using w3.css

```
<button onclick="w3_open()" class="w3-button w3-opacity w3-black">Yesterday</button>
<div id="id01" class="w3-panel w3-white w3-card w3-display-container">
<span onclick="document.getElementById('id01').style.display='none'" 
    class="w3-button w3-display-topright">&times;</span>
<p class="w3-text-blue"><b>email.zip</b></p>
<p>https://www.w3schools.com/lib/email.zip</p>
<p class="w3-text-blue">Show in folder</p>
</div>
<div id="id02" class="test w3-panel w3-white w3-card w3-display- 
 container">

<span onclick="document.getElementById('id02').style.display='none'" 
    class="w3-button w3-display-topright">&times;</span>
<p class="w3-text-blue"><b>email.zip</b></p>
<p>https://www.w3schools.com/lib/email.zip</p>
<p class="w3-text-blue">Show in folder</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

If you give the li's and the corresponding divs the same `class`, then you can say something like

```
function showDivs() {
$("li").click(function() {
    $(".Content").hide();
    clickedID = $(this).attr("class");
    $('div#'+clickedID).fadeIn("slow");

})
```

}

Comment: *"If you give the li's and the corresponding divs the same `id`..."* [`id` values ***must*** be completely unique on the page](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/elements.html#the-id-attribute).